# Montando .eslintrc, como escrever?

Tags: javascript, react

Peguei um projeto com esse eslint:

```
   {
  "extends": [
    "keystone"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": [2, {"vars": "all", "args": "after-used"}],
  },
}
```

Outro com esse eslint aqui

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "fetchAPI": true,
    "_": true,
    "err": true
  },
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "arrowFunctions": true,
    "blockBindings": true,
    "classes": true,
    "defaultParams": true,
    "destructuring": true,
    "forOf": true,
    "generators": false,
    "modules": true,
    "objectLiteralComputedProperties": true,
    "objectLiteralDuplicateProperties": false,
    "objectLiteralShorthandMethods": true,
    "objectLiteralShorthandProperties": true,
    "spread": true,
    "superInFunctions": true,
    "templateStrings": true,
    "jsx": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "strict": [2, "never"],
    "no-var": 2,
    "no-shadow": 0,
    "no-shadow-restricted-names": 2,
    "no-unused-vars": [2, {
      "vars": "local",
      "args": "after-used"
    }],
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "comma-dangle": [2, "never"],
    "no-cond-assign": [2, "always"],
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-debugger": 1,
    "no-alert": 1,
    "no-constant-condition": 1,
    "no-dupe-keys": 2,
    "no-duplicate-case": 2,
    "no-empty": 2,
    "no-ex-assign": 2,
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 0,
    "no-extra-semi": 2,
    "no-func-assign": 2,
    "no-inner-declarations": 2,
    "no-invalid-regexp": 2,
    "no-irregular-whitespace": 2,
    "no-obj-calls": 2,
    "quote-props": ['error', "as-needed", {"keywords": true , "unnecessary": false }],
    "no-sparse-arrays": 2,
    "no-unreachable": 2,
    "use-isnan": 2,
    "block-scoped-var": 2,
    "consistent-return": 0,
    "curly": [2, "multi-line"],
    "default-case": 0,
    "dot-notation": [2, {
      "allowKeywords": true,
      "allowPattern": "^\\w+(_\\w+)+$"
    }],
    "eqeqeq": 2,
    "guard-for-in": 2,
    "no-caller": 2,
    "no-else-return": 2,
    "no-eq-null": 2,
    "no-eval": 2,
    "no-extend-native": 2,
    "no-extra-bind": 2,
    "no-fallthrough": 2,
    "no-floating-decimal": 2,
    "no-implied-eval": 2,
    "no-lone-blocks": 2,
    "no-loop-func": 0,
    "no-multi-str": 2,
    "no-native-reassign": 2,
    "no-new": 2,
    "no-new-func": 2,
    "no-new-wrappers": 2,
    "no-octal": 2,
    "no-octal-escape": 2,
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "no-proto": 2,
    "no-redeclare": 2,
    "no-return-assign": 2,
    "no-script-url": 2,
    "no-self-compare": 2,
    "no-sequences": 2,
    "no-throw-literal": 2,
    "no-with": 2,
    "radix": 0,
    "vars-on-top": 2,
    "wrap-iife": [2, "any"],
    "yoda": 2,
    "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
    "brace-style": [2,
      "1tbs", {
      "allowSingleLine": true
    }],
    "quotes": [
      2, "single", "avoid-escape"
    ],
    "no-undefined": 0,
    "no-undef": "error",
    "camelcase": 0,
    "comma-spacing": [2, {
      "before": false,
      "after": true
    }],
    "comma-style": [2, "last"],
    "eol-last": 2,
    "func-names": ['error', 'never'],
    "key-spacing": [2, {
        "beforeColon": false,
        "afterColon": true
    }],
    "new-cap": [2, {
      "newIsCap": true
    }],
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [2, {
      "max": 2
    }],
    "no-nested-ternary": 2,
    "no-new-object": 2,
    "no-spaced-func": 2,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 2,
    "no-extra-parens": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "one-var": 0,
    "padded-blocks": 0,
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "semi-spacing": [2, {
      "before": false,
      "after": true
    }],
    "keyword-spacing": 2,
    "space-before-blocks": 2,
    "space-before-function-paren": [2, "always"],
    "space-infix-ops": 2,
    "spaced-comment": 0,
    "react/display-name": 0,
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 2,
    "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"],
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 2,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 2,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": [2, "allow-in-func"],
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 2,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 2,
    "react/prop-types": 2,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 2,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 2,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 2,
    "react/sort-comp": [0, {
      "order": []
    }]
  }
}
```

Minha duvida é a seguinte eu escrevo o eslint de acordo com o que vou escrevendo ou existe um design patterns para cada tipo de projeto? Toda vez que iniciar um projeto e for usar o lint tenho que construir um eslint diferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define as regras de organização de código que queres implementar e cria um ficheiro de configuração com o que decidiste.

Se usares sempre as mesmas regras é so copiar um ficheiro, se tiveres regras diferentes (porque outros na equipa gostam de outras regras ou porque o contrato o exige), então tens de fazer um novo...

Um exemplo: na biblioteca MooTools a equipa decidiu [uma série de regras](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Syntax-and-Coding-Style-Conventions) que toda a gente respeitava, mais tarde isso foi [implementado em eslint](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/.eslintrc) por mim e pelo Tim Wienk. Estas regras eram específicas da comunidade e nada obrigatório para todos os projetos JavaScript por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado! Então é uma questão de regra de padrão do time de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @FrederickSilva sim, depende da equipa.

Comment: Muito legal essa documentação das regras que são utilizadas no eslint, @Sergio você aconselha a documentar a cada nova regra adicionada, ou separa um tempo no roadmap para fazer esse review depois?

Comment: @FrederickSilva se a equipa decide uma regra nova é correr o código todo e mudar logo. Senão vais estar a criar o hábito de não seguir regras.